# unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386, skipping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

9.3 and rails 3.2.13 in my application  to create  PDF so i install 
**gem install wkhtmltopdf** and **gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary -v '0.9.9.1'** but i got following message how to solve this

**gem install wkhtmltopdf**

Successfully installed wkhtmltopdf-0.1.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for wkhtmltopdf-0.1.2...

```
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386, skipping
unable to convert "\xCE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for wkhtmltopdf-0.1.2...
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386, skipping
unable to convert "\xCE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386, skipping
```

**gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary -v '0.9.9.1'**

```
Fetching: wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1.gem (100%)^[[1;2C
Successfully installed wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1...
unable to convert "\xA3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x64, skipping
unable to convert "\xC0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386, skipping
unable to convert "\xCE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1...
unable to convert "\xA3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x64, skipping
unable to convert "\xC0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386, skipping
unable to convert "\xCE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386, skipping
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is while installing the documentation.  Try

```
gem install wkhtmltopdf --no-document
```

Comment: +1, that definitely makes a lot of sense, and it also fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation issue. Do this: `gem update rdoc` before gem installations. It should fix it. Or just ignore the documentation installation with `--no-document` key